# Generate random number in jqtpl

Tags: node.js, express, jquery-templates

Is it possible to generate random value in jQuery templates?

I using jQuery templates with expressjs and node.js and I'm trying generate some "dynamic" position elements on page. So I am trying to generate a random number in jqtpl and using it in inline css in layouts.

Comment: if one of these answers worked for you please click the checkmark next to it in order to help future visitors with similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could for example use [hat](https://github.com/substack/node-hat). Especially the `rack` function.

```
Call rack() repeatedly to generate new IDs which are checked for collisions.
```

**code**

```
var hat = require('hat');
var rack = hat.rack(9, 10);

console.log(rack());
console.log(rack());
```

**output**

```
$ node test.js
109
461
```

Comment: i need generate the random value in jqtpl not in node because in node there isn't a problem. :)

Comment: To be honest I have not yet inspected jqtpl properly. Hopefully somebody else can give you a proper answer!

Comment: thnx i hope somebody can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

The following will work.  The routing is an example and for reference https://github.com/kof/node-jqtpl/

Node:

```
app.get('/randomtest', function(req, res){
    res.render('random.html', 
      {rnd: function(min, max) {
        return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
      }
    });
});
```

Template:

```
${rnd(1,10)}
```

The min/max control what gets outputted.